# Using and displaying more than 2 decimal places

Tags: vba, format, ms-project

I want to use more than 2 decimal places to make calculations with my MS Project project.

So far i wasn't able to find any resource which tells how to show more than 2 decimal in a field (like Work or cost, for example), neither how to truncate numbers instead of rounding them (lets say, USD 12.357 to USD 12.35 instead of USD 12.36).

Is there any way of doing this? It could be through VBA or any method you can come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use more than 2 decimal places, just not in the user interface.** 
The UI truncates displayed *and* entered values to 2 decimals. However, values entered and accessed via VBA do not have this limitation.

For example, using the Intermediate window (VBA), enter the cost for the first two tasks of the active project and then request the values to prove they are stored as entered, up to 16 digits:

```
ActiveProject.Tasks(1).Cost = 0.1234567890123456789
ActiveProject.Tasks(2).Cost = 123456789012.123456789

? ActiveProject.Tasks(1).Cost
 0.123456789012346 
? ActiveProject.Tasks(2).Cost
 123456789012.123
```

---

**To show the value in the UI as stored, customize a text field using the Format function:**

[image]